# Entity Framework SaveChanges bug

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm not really sure if this is a bug, but looks like to me. I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.1 code first, and I have the following classes:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

}

public class Country
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(3)]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to update the user password with the following code I get an error:

```
User _user = db.Users.Find(Id);
_user.Password = Password;
db.Entry(_user).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Error:
Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details. The validation errors are: The Country field is required."}

The point is that if I do ANY interaction with the property _user.Country.Id, it works. Like this:

```
User _user = db.Users.Find(Id);
_user.Password = Password;
Console.Write(_user.Country.Id.ToString());
db.Entry(_user).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Any idea if this is a known bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have configured the entity with independent association (there is `CountryId` property on `User`) and with `Required` attribute, that means the `Country` property needs to have a value.

This code will not load the `Country` because it's loaded with lazy loading.

```
User _user = db.Users.Find(Id);
```

Unless you do something like.

```
var country = _user.Country; // this will load the Country
```

Or you can load the `Country` together with the main query using eager loading.

```
User _user = db.Users.Include(x => x.Country).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);
```

Tips:

- Marking with the `_user` with `EntityState.Modified` is not necessary because it's a proxy, the change tracker will know if the entity will be modified.

Comment: Or you could simply disable lazy loading altogether.

    `dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`

Comment: Thanks!! This really explained and solved the problem.

Comment: @LazyTarget, No, the point is, `Country` has to have a value, either lazy loading, eager loading, or set it manually with the id and attach it to the context

Comment: @LazyTarget, disabling lazy loading will not automatically load all navigation properties with eager loading, it's still need to be explicitly mentioned with `Include`, without it, eager loading doesn't happen

Comment: @YuliamChandra Oh I thought so. What does the property change then?

Comment: I'm not sure what property change you are referring to, if you mean change tracker, you can read it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456848%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @YuliamChandra I mean the `db.Context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled`. Found [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) that explains everything

Comment: Still not sure which line you meant, but setting `LazyLoadingEnabled` to false, doesn't mean eager loading is automatically on, `Include` is required

Answer (score 0):

I've never explicitly set the State when I've used Entity Framework. If you remove the line `db.Entry(_user).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;` will your code still work and save data to the database?

Comment: Yes! I added this line trying to solve the problem. If I remove it I'll keep having the same behavior.